# naudio stops recording immediately

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to record the user using his microphone with naudio, but right after the recording starts the `waveSource_RecordingStopped` gets called and it doesn't record anymore.

I'd like to know why this is happening and how can I fix it.

here is my code:

```
private WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;
private WaveIn waveSource = null;
private static bool isRecording = false;

private void record_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
        string saveLocation = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("\\voice-assistant_client\\voice-assistant_client\\bin\\Debug", "");
        SoundPlayer startRecording = new SoundPlayer(directory + "\\sounds\\beep-start.wav");
        SoundPlayer stopRecording = new SoundPlayer(directory + "\\sounds\\beep-stop.wav");
        bool hasMicrophone = true;

        if (!isRecording)
        {
            waveSource = new WaveIn();
            waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

            try
            {
                waveSource.StartRecording();
                waveSource.StopRecording();
            }
            catch (Exception exeption)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exeption);
                hasMicrophone = false;
                this.error.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (hasMicrophone)
            {
                this.error.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
                waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

                waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(saveLocation + "/Test0001.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);

                startRecording.PlaySync();
                waveSource.StartRecording();

                isRecording = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            waveSource.StopRecording();             
            stopRecording.PlaySync();

            isRecording = false;
        }
    }

    void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveFile.Flush();
        }
    }

    void waveSource_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveSource != null)
        {
            waveSource.Dispose();
            waveSource = null;
        }

        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Dispose();
            waveFile = null;
        }
    }
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: The reason of exception is clear. You have set it to null and when calling again it’s going in else part and you are calling method ok null. So tell us what exactly you’re requirement is.

Comment: at the start of the program the waveSource is indeed null but after I press the record button I put in it a `new WaveIn` which means it's not null anymore. But my problem is that the `waveSource_RecordingStopped` is being called right after I start the recording and then when I try to stop it the waveSource is already null. So I don't understand why `waveSource_RecordingStopped is being called without  `waveSource.StopRecording()` - @viveknuna